# single board computers sharing a microswitch

Tags: sbc

I have two independent single board computers (SBCs) connected to a common ground.

I wish to have an input pin on each (both used concurrently) connected to a microswitch.
When the microswitch closes both SBC pins will go low.

### Is this OK?

Haven't been to this board before.  Hope this is the right place to add info.
Not and electrical engineer.

Both SBCs powered by same 12v source.
Both SBCs and all peripherals (switches, etc.) grounded to single point.

Both SBC inputs are +5v.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What makes you think it would not be ok?

Comment: It's a fair question. It depends what the input circuit of each SBC is and what input voltage range they use. Is it two of the same SBC running from the same power supply?

Comment: you can always use a dpst if in doubt, but it sounds fine.

Answer (score 2):

Common ground and both pins set into input mode, as long as you keep both powered on at the same time. Shutting power off one while the pin is held high could lead to problems.

Other alternatives is using a Double Pole switch, or using two transistor or optocoupler circuits to make each board independent on power. Really just need a few resistors and wire as well as the transistor or optos.